# Can't install Sharp

Tags: node.js, npm, sharp

When running `sudo npm i sharp --save` I get the following errors:

```
> sharp@0.21.3 install /home/server/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Using cached /home/ronny/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
ERR! sharp EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/server/node_modules/sharp/vendor'
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/page/install for required dependencies
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/server/node_modules/sharp/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.18.0-13-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/server/node_modules/sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.21.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.21.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ronny/.npm/_logs/2019-01-28T20_33_46_476Z-debug.log
```

I have the same project running on another machine, and there, the install works flawlessly. But on my other machine (both run Linux Ubuntu) I am facing the above error.

I couldn't find any solution for this error. That's why I am asking for help here.

Comment: gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/server/node_modules/sharp/build' (SUDO?)

Comment: I entered the command with `sudo`, so I  should have permission

Answer (score 38, accepted):

this worked for me. 
`npm install --unsafe-perm`

please refer to the following discussion
https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1627#issuecomment-477109851

Comment: I also found [this blogpost](https://geedew.com/What-does-unsafe-perm-in-npm-actually-do/) helpful to understand the reasons for this. Simply put, npm tries to switch to a user account when installing modules, as modules installed as root can be only used by a root process. It is considered unsafe to run regular processes as root, hence the parameter name.

Comment: To make this work for me, I use the following command: 'pnpm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp'

Answer (score 21):

That actually helped me, using node 14.20.1

```
npm install sharp --ignore-scripts
```

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way is:

```
brew uninstall vips
```

And then:

```
npm install
```

Comment: Can we shed some light as to why this works, please? Why the upvotes?

Comment: Assuming you're on a Mac with Homebrew installed...

Answer (score 11):

For **Apple M1** `brew install vips` then `npm install --unsafe-perm`

If it does not solved your problem find more in this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560211/mac-m1-something-went-wrong-installing-the-sharp-module/67566332#67566332)

> - xcode-select --install
> - brew install gcc
> - brew reinstall vips
> - brew info vips
> - npm i

Answer (score 8):

`npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp` worked for me

taken from : https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2128#issuecomment-600232917

I am using a **M1 mac**

Answer (score 7):

The problem with Node v13.14.0+, the problem will be solved

```
npm install sharp@0.23.2
```

You should downgrade Node version to >=10.0.0 if you are using sharp 0.22.1

Comment: Problem persists in version `0.28.3`

Comment: You need to downgrade Sharp or Nodejs version. You need to check compatibility because higher versions often cause conflicts

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this error by downgrading `node version to 10.0.0`. It really works!

Comment: In my case downgrading from v16.13.0 to v14.16.1 solves the problem

Answer (score 4):

delete **package-lock.json** and **node_modules** 
 then try to install packages `npm install` 
 Worked for me.

Comment: it work for me,
my node version v14.17.0 
npm version 7.17.0
sharp version  "^0.27.0"

Answer (score 3):

Try yarn instead of npm, it works for me (docker, official node image 16.x)

```
yarn add sharp
```

Answer (score 2):

So first the error says Permission denied.
install it using 
`sudo` 
when you use `sudo` in the [sharp documentation](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install)! it says that you have to use 
`npm install --unsafe-perm`

I would recommend:

- go to `/home/ronny/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz` (in your error code)
- remove the file: `libvips-8.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz`
- in your terminal type: `npm install --unsafe-perm` (this will install the deleted lib)
- `npm install sharp`

Then I think I should work fine. These steps fixed my issue, I had the same issue.
Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for my Apple M1 and I ran the next comands:

- I removed node_modules
- I deleted package-lock.json
- Run: `brew install vips`
- Run: `npm install --unsafe-perm`

And it works

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well. I installed the required (6Gb!!) Visual Studio 2022 Build tools, but even after reboot it was still not working.

Another thing I tried was setting the following:

```
npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
```

still didn't work.

Finally, I deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. I deleted the sharp module from `package.json` and install everything.

Then I run:

```
npm install sharp --save
```

And finally it worked

Answer (score 1):

Late but I'm telling you what worked for me. If you have previously installed any dependency that works exactly the same as sharp, remove that **`dependency`** from your **`Package.json`** file and then run

```
npm install sharp
```

Comment: I faced a problem with sharp on multiple OS/distros as I started working on a project about 3 years old. This solution solved my problem on MacOS BigSur, Windows 11 and CentOS 7.9.

And a side note, this problem *might* be caused by missing python 3.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped. I faced the issue in NodeJs(Javascript)

Answer (score 1):

npm install --platform=darwin --arch=x64 sharp

https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install

I'm using a Macbook pro M1
nodeJS version v16.14.2
It works for me

Answer (score 1):

macOS should install the vips package first

```bash
brew install vips
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue occurred on an M1 Mac.

What worked:

```bash
$ brew uninstall vips # I believe this makes sharp use the version $ it's compatible with
$ yarn install sharp@next
```

I am on a react-native project. Node version: v18.17.0

Answer (score 0):

Running npx create-strapi-app my-project --quickstart on windows and got the same error, had to install C++ for desktop development from visual studio and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to install Python first. After that, it went well.
[Install Python here.](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

```
npm i sharp
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder
```

Answer (score 0):

One other thing you can try is to open up task manager and kill node js process that is currently running

Answer (score 0):

For me, reading the logs helped me find a solution.

Yarn output:

```
➤ YN0009: │ sharp@npm:0.30.7 couldn't be built successfully (exit code 1, logs can be found here: /private/var/folders/yc/78ts3g2s4mxdbxsln5kz16dm0000gn/T/xfs-49e52cab/build.log)
```

And in that log file I noticed this line:

```
env: python: No such file or directory
```

I only had a `python3` binary, no `python`, so I symlinked `python3` to `/usr/local/bin/python`, which allowed me to install sharp.

```bash
ln -sf $(which python3) /usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: i ran across a syntax error using this apprach. I think actually using python2 for python makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Linux/Ubuntu: I face the issue.[image: error] node version 18.12.1, but first try to install node-gyp

- `sudo npm install -g node-gyp`

then remove old `package-lock.json` and again try to install

- `npm i sharp` this time it's work, than again install all the package
- `npm install`
  [image: success]

note: if you not fixed it. Please check out [sharp-installation guide](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install)

Answer (score 0):

I add one command before 'npm install' executed.

```
- USER=`whoami` && sudo chown $USER:$USER .
- npm install --verbose

# node => 16
# npm => 8.11.0
# sharp => 0.31.3
```

Comment: I thought I'm solved. But It was not

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found a very good solution. If you use unsafe perm, the module will get installed but might not work when you try to use it, none of mine did. The solution is to install the latest version of node js. The default ubuntu repository does not offer the latest version unfortunately thus one needs to add the node js repository with the latest node js version. To do this, curl is required.

First remove the currently installed node js

```
sudo apt remove node js
```

Also remove the currently installed npm

```
sudo apt remove npm
```

Curl is installed with the advanced package tool as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

After installing curl, now the good node js repository may be added as follows:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Now the latest version of node js may be installed with the advanced package tool

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Checking the node js version, you'll get version >= 18

```
node -v
```

Also checking the npm version

```
npm -v
```

Now one may proceed to install the module and it will work perfectly. In my case it was sharp

```
sudo npm install sharp
```

[I got my solution here. Thank you for reading, happy coding](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-node-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Using Pnpm; on M1 Mac, this helped:

```
pnpm install sharp --config.arch=x64 --config.platform=linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using node 14 and I resolved installing sharp version 29.3

Answer (score -3):

```
npm install --unsafe-perm -g cordova-res
```

Comment: What does Cordova have to do with this?