# Have an issue with the "sharp" module when using "npm install" and "npm run develop"

Tags: npm

I am trying to use npm to run a webpage that I cloned from github. When I executed npm install, I had an issue reporting:

```
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'E:\\SuperNova\\lab-site\\node_modules\\eslint',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\eslint\node_modules'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'E:\\SuperNova\\lab-site\\node_modules\\eslint\\node_modules'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'E:\\SuperNova\\lab-site\\node_modules\\@parcel\\cache',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\@parcel\cache'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild 
&& node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.14.2/libvips-8.14.2-win32-x64.tar.br
npm ERR! sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
npm ERR! sharp: Installation error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: github.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.github-debug.com, DNS:github-

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\86189\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-06T01_38_29_766Z-debug-0.log
```

then I searched through(found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409953/cant-install-sharp)) and used `npm install sharp --ignore-scripts` , and no errors poped out.

But then I use npm run develop, I again received an issuee with module sharp:

```
PS E:\SuperNova\lab-site> npm run develop

> lab-demo@1.0.0 develop
> gatsby develop

success compile gatsby files - 1.952s
success load gatsby config - 0.042s

 ERROR  UNKNOWN

Error in "E:/SuperNova/lab-site/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp/gatsby-node":
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-win32-x64.node'
Require stack:
- E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\sharp\lib\sharp.js
- E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\sharp\lib\constructor.js
- E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\sharp\lib\index.js
- E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp\safe-sharp.js
- E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp\index.js
- E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp\gatsby-node.js

Possible solutions:
- Install with verbose logging and look for errors: "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --foreground-scripts --verbose sharp"
- Install for the current win32-x64 runtime: "npm install --platform=win32 --arch=x64 sharp"
- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install



  Error: Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module
  Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-win32-x64.node'
  Require stack:
  - E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\sharp\lib\sharp.js
  - E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\sharp\lib\constructor.js
  - E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\sharp\lib\index.js
  - E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp\safe-sharp.js
  - E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp\index.js
  - E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-sharp\gatsby-node.js
  Possible solutions:
  - Install with verbose logging and look for errors: "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --foreground-scripts --verbose sharp"
  - Install for the current win32-x64 runtime: "npm install --platform=win32 --arch=x64 sharp"
  - Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install
```

I searched this issue and found another info: [Can't install Sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409953/cant-install-sharp)

I followed the suggestions by using `npm rebuild --verbose sharp` and the error messages are:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\SuperNova\lab-site\node_modules\sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild 
&& node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.14.4/libvips-8.14.4-win32-x64.tar.br
npm ERR! sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
npm ERR! sharp: Installation error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: github.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.github-debug.com, DNS:github-debug.com
npm verb exit 1
npm verb unfinished npm timer build 1693967108358
npm verb unfinished npm timer build:deps 1693967108359
npm verb unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1693967108360
npm verb unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/sharp 1693967108360
npm verb code 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\86189\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-06T02_25_07_397Z-debug-0.log
```

It seems that module sharp did not successfully installed.  I looked several stackoverflow related posts but could not solve it successfully.

I appreciate if anyone could solve this issue.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably due to the npm registry.
I use `nrm use taobao` and everything goes all right.